# Javascript check box is checked issue with trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript file code is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox[id^='chkbox_']").on('click',function(){
       var chkbox = $(this);
       if(chkbox.is(':checked')){
          alert('In if');
       } else {
          alert('In else');
       }
    });
    $("#" + id).trigger('click');
});
```

This code gives me `In else` .

I don't understand why and what is the solution for this

Comment: it work fine form me http://jsfiddle.net/dy4uzn51/

Comment: its working fine!! Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vhvpL5z3/)

Comment: @ekans it is not working with jquery 1.8.3
Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/vhvpL5z3/4/

Comment: @RahulVarma you too please check this. Although this works in newer library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This answer seems to only apply to versions before 1.9 or so, when the "bug" [seems to have been fixed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3827).

I've been struck by this problem too. The reason is that when you actually click the checkbox with your mouse, its state is set first and then its click handlers are executed. If you trigger the click using jQuery, the click handlers are executed first and the state set afterwards.

One solution is to trigger the native javascript click handler like this: `checkbox[0].click()`, which does the same as jQuery's `.click()`/`.trigger('click')` but in the right order.

Another is to do `checkbox.attr('checked', true).triggerHandler('click')`, where the status is set first and `triggerHandler()` only executes the handler and not the default behavior (checking the box).

Both solutions should allow your code to work regardless of if the click was real or triggered.

Comment: Thanks i worked, and explaining this is such a nice manner.
Thanks a lot @Peter Herdenborg

Comment: Glad I could help! But I see others claiming it should work anyway. Maybe they are correct and my knowledge is outdated. You could try upgrading jQuery instead.

Comment: Mine jquery version is 1.8.3 and it was not working with that.

Comment: Thanks for checking that. Their bug report page is a bit hard to interpret. Not sure where I got 1.7 from now, but I reckon it was fixed in 1.9 (as Explore-X suggests in his answer). Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your jquery library issue. or browser issue. Its working fine for me. You can you latest jquery above 1.8.

`click to view answer`http://jsfiddle.net/dy4uzn51/2/